# Getting text from doc and docx

Tags: python-3.x, search, docx, doc

I'm using a computer with Windows 7 and python 3.3 installed on it. 
At my organization we have thousands of documents which are not organized. 
I want to create a program that opens doc/docx files, searches the text for certain keywords and then rearranges the documents.
I'm looking for a way to search the text of a word file (doc/docx) for certain words, it has to be on Windows, and it has to be able to search both doc and docx.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

a .docx document is a Zip archive in OpenXML format: you have first to uncompress it.

After this you can run:

```
# Import the module
from docx import *

# Open the .docx file
document = opendocx('A document.docx')

# Search returns true if found    
search(document,'your search string')
```

Comment: I have thousands of documents, I can't uncompress every single one of them, it's not practical.

Comment: But it's not dealing with doc :-(

Answer (score 0):

One can use the textract library. It take care of both "doc" as well as "docx"

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension")
```

You can even use 'antiword' (sudo apt-get install     antiword) and then convert doc to first into docx and then read through docx2txt.

antiword filename.doc > filename.docx
Ultimately, textract in the backend is using antiword.

Comment: the installation goes through, and fails at the end... :-( appears it doesn't work on python 3.3 :-(

Comment: Can you send a screenshot?

Comment: when installing through command promp pip install textract it says "build failed" in red, and then some more lines in red and closes the window...too fast for me to screenshot XD is there a way to freeze it?

Comment: Great Library but installation doesn't go through Python 3.3

Comment: Installation goes through brew. For those interested, you can also convert a .doc file into pdf preserving the images, then extract text with OCR using pytesseract.